# Using %s format specifier with boost::format and std::string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-format

I know that using the `%s` format specifier and `std::string` like this leads to undefined behaviour:

```
std::string myString = "test";
printf("%s", myString);
```

**But is it save to use the same specifier and a `std::string` with `boost::format`?**

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main() 
{
   std::string myString = "test";

   boost::format fmt("%s");
   fmt % myString;

   std::cout << fmt.str();

   return 0;
}
```

`%s` specifies a (const) `char*`, but I provide a `std::string`. Could this lead to UB too?

Comment: I may be missing the point, but why not pass std::string.c_str()?

Comment: Because I found a lot of those calls in some legacy code, and I am trying to decide whether I need to fix it or not. Also I would like to know how to use the %s specifier correctly in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is safe to use `%s` with `boost::format` and `std::string`. In contrast to `printf`, the type character in the format string "does not impose the concerned arguments to be of a restricted set of types, but merely sets the flags that are associated with this type specification."

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#printf_directives